# Google managed SSL certificate stuck on "Provisioning" with FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE for domains

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs), I have deployed an app on GKE, in a regional auto-pilot cluster. I made it publicly accessible using an ingress linked to a domain I own, with a static IP, and a Google Managed Certificate for HTTPS.

Accessing my app by the ip, or my domain name works well in HTTP, but when using HTTPS, I get a `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH mydomain.com uses an incompatible protocol` error (I have this error using the IP, and also using the domain). Indeed, when consulting my managed certificate on the Google Cloud Cnsole I see that it is still in `PROVISIONING` status (it has been more than 3 days now), and I have a warning triangle next to my domain specifying `FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE`.

I have checked my domain name setup and it has a `A` record pointing to the static IP used by my ingress (I configured it while doing the tutorial). I've also checked my load balancer on GKE and it has a target proxy for HTTPS using my managed certificate

Here is my ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-api
  annotations:
    # specifies the name of the global IP address resource to be associated with the HTTP(S) Load Balancer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-app-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
  labels:
    app: my-app-api
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: my-app-api
      port:
        name: http
```

and my managed certificate

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - mydomain.com
    - www.mydomain.com
```

I've applied them using `kubectl apply -f my-file.yaml`

I don't understand what I did wrong or what is missing. Can someone please help me make my app work in HTTPS please?

**Edit**
Here is the output of `kubectl describe managedcertificate managed-cert`

```
...
Spec:
  Domains:
    mydomain.com
    www.mydomain.com
Status:
  Certificate Name:    mcrt-...
  Certificate Status:  Provisioning
  Domain Status:
    Domain:  www.mydomain.com
    Status:  FailedNotVisible
    Domain:  mydomain.com
    Status:  FailedNotVisible
Events:      <none>
```

Comment: Did you solve this?
Are you sure that `nslookup mydomain.com` points to the the external static IP?
Also, can you show the output of `kubectl describe managedcertificate managed-cert`?

Comment: I could't solve this. Yes, nslookup does point to my static IP address. I've edited my post to include the output of `kubectl describe managedcertificate managed-cert`, metadata excluded so that it doesn't take too much space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like it was due to a misconfiguration on my DNS. I added the `A` record, but when taking a closer look at the [update DNS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#update-dns) part, I noticed that my `CNAME` record was misconfigured